# C++, Qt: QProcess - How to *avoid* capturing STDOUT

Tags: c++, qt, system-calls

I am looking for a way to start a process and not to capture its STDOUT/STDERR.

I.e. I want the STDOUT/STDERR to be printed directly to the shell, just like in a regular stdlib `system()` call

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using  `QProcess::setProcessChannelMode(ProcessChannelMode mode)` with argument `QProcess::ForwardedChannels`. Here is the documentation entry: [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessChannelMode)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. There are a lot of misleading examples on the web, in which they call such methods after the "start()". So, even if it sounds trivial, I want to mention here that it is needed to call this function before you start the process

Answer (score 0):

Another option for something equivalent to a stdlib `system()` call, is `QProcess::startDetached()`  static method. Note that it will not wait for the process to finish, again, like the stdlib `system()` call

Comment: but this does a lot more than changing the output mode.